# Downloading from a dynamic list of files in Django Admin

Tags: python, django

I currently have a django app which generates PDFs and saves them to a specific directory.  From the admin interface I want to have some way to view the list of files within that directory (similar to models.FilePathField()), but also be able to download them.  I realize that django was never intended to actually serve files, and I have been tinkering with [django-sendfile](http://www.sensibledevelopment.com/2010/11/django-sendfile-an-for-abstraction-large-file-serving-in-django/), as a possible option.  It just doesn't seem like there is any way to create a dynamic list of files other than with FilePathField (which I don't believe can suite my purposes).

Answer (score 1):

Would this project fit your needs? http://code.google.com/p/django-filebrowser/

Comment: I'm checking it out now, but it seems like it's intended for more complex purposes than what I mean to do.  For reference, this is the admin page that I want to modify: [link](http://i.imgur.com/KvVlO.png).  All I need to do is create some method of retrieving files from the server based on that drop-down menu.  It needs to be on that particular page and not a separate view.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up realizing that I was going about the problem in a more complicated manner than was necessary.  Using two separate views trivializes the issue.  I was just under the impression that the admin interface would include such a basic feature.

What I did was create a download_list view to display the files in the directory, and a download_file view which uses django-sendfile to serve the file to the end-user.  Download_file simply parses through the directory with listdir(), checks if the extension is valid and sends the complete file path to the download_file function (after the user selects one).

Answer (score 0):

Are the files in a directory that is served by your webserver? If all you want to do is list and download the files, it may be easier just to have a link to the directory with all the files in it and let the webserver take care of listing and serving the files. I understand this may not be the ideal solution for you, but it does avoid having Django serve static files, which is a task best left to the webserver.